# Array_agg() functionally in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have table with followings columns.

```
Emp name,emp id,emp ph no 
X,1,99
X,2,10
Y,2,30
```

Output:

```
x,1,(99,10)
```

Based on emp name and order by emp Id form the phone array

Query:

```
select emp-name,array_agg(emp_phno order by emp_id) from emp
```

Error:

> function array_agg called with an invalid number or type of parameters

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have to create the array type first (if you have permissions to do so), and then use that as the `array_expression` argument.

Comment: See the [ARRAY_AGG documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/~_sY_PYVxZzTnqKq45UXkQ/yRRDUG9Qgtdik7iGigWt7A)

Comment: @Andrew can you provide an example code?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define an array type to hold the results of your aggregation. This would be something like

```
CREATE TYPE emp_phno_arr AS VARCHAR(10) ARRAY[5];
```

In the above SQL note the size of the `VARCHAR`. I set it to 10 because that's the length of a North American phone number. You might want it to be a different length. Also not the size of the array. I set it to 5. This means the aggregation will allow for at most 5 phone numbers per person. If there are more than 5 number the aggregation will fail. But you can change the size of the array as needed.

Next you will want to do the aggregation.

```
SELECT emp-name, ARRAY_AGG(emp_phno, NEW emp_phno_arr()) FROM emp GROUP BY  emp-name;
```

Note the second argument to the `ARRAY_AGG` function. It calls the constructor for the new array type you created in the first SQL statement.